# MATLAB: Error using * Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, struct, dimensions

So I'm working on a function that will receive inputs from from a user-defined structure to plot an ellipsoid, but Matlab keeps spitting out this error. Here's the portion I'm having trouble with:

```
theta = 0:(0.1):2*pi;
phi = 0:(0.1):pi;
a1 = ellipsoid_in(1).major_axis;
b1 = ellipsoid_in(1).minor_axis;
c1 = ellipsoid_in(1).transverse_axis;

x1 = a1*sin(phi)*cos(theta);
y1 = b1*sin(phi)*sin(theta);
w1 = c1*cos(phi);
plot3(x1,y1,w1)
grid on
hold on
x2 = x1;
y2 = y1;
w2 = w1;
plot3(x2,y2,z2)
xx = [x1;x2];
yy = [y1;y2];
ww = [w1;w2];
```

The error is occurring in my first (x1) equation and I've already tried using the .* operator on them all with the same result. I'm guessing the problem is coming from the 1x2 structure I'm calling, but I don't know how to fix it. The variables for the structures all correspond to scalars. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you've really used the `.*` operator instead of `*`, you wouldn't continue to get the same error - you could get other errors, but not that one, since `.*` doesn't do matrix multiplication, it does element-wise multiplication. So... what you you mean by "same result"? Also, what is the type and size of `a1`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I do get the .* error, it's just worded similarly. a1 is a 1x1 double.

Comment: To diagnose "matrix dimensions must agree" errors, put `size` commands of each part of the equation on the lines before it, then it's obvious what the problem is. (i.e. do `size(a1)`, `size(phi)`, `size(theta)` before `x1= ...` and look at the output).

Comment: regarding the answer of tmpearce, have a look at [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
theta = 0:(0.1):2*pi;
phi = 0:(0.1):pi;
```

With the above two lines, you've created two vectors. These are different lengths (since one goes to `pi` and the other to `2*pi`, by the same step size.

You do want to use element-wise multiplication (`.*`), but you need your vectors to be the same lengths... otherwise, which elements get multiplied together?